# Wordpress DELETing pages ON ITS OWN

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress(4.9.8–en) keeps on deleting pages on its own,
Sometimes I can restore them from trash,
and always I get error "Error in restoring from Trash."
but the page gets restored
and sometimes the page even disappears from Trash
and you cant even restore.

and this is happening randomly with any page.
it happens mostly when I add a new page and update, its trashed automatically.

and sometimes it just deletes some random pages.

I have NO ADD-ONs Installed.
No Customization.
No settings Updated.
This is the same case with fresh installation of WP from GoDaddy (MyHosting).
This has been happening from last week and so...(I just started my new site)
Any help appreciated...

Sample Content In Page:
http://www.happy2helptech.com/cityhomeservices.in/

```
<div class="wrapper" style="background:tomato;border: 10px solid black;">
  <header class="header"></header>
  <aside class="aside aside-1"><img class="r10img" src="http://www.happy2helptech.com/cityhomeservices.in/wp-content/uploads/computer1.jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px;border:solid black;border-radius:10%;"></aside>
  <article class="main" >
      <li style="margin-left:10px;padding:10px;">General Computer Repair
      </li>
      <li style="margin-left:10px;padding:10px;">Printer Or Scanner Repair
      </li>
      <li style="margin-left:10px;padding:10px;">Computer Hardware Repair
      </li>
      <li style="margin-left:10px;padding:10px;">Motherboard Repair
      </li>
      <li style="margin-left:10px;padding:10px;">Bios Problem
      </li>
  </article>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</div>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Content usually doesn't delete itself on its own, so either someone else is doing it (check if you have unknown usernames created on your site) or there's a malware doing it (scan your site with Sucuri or any other anti-malware plugin/service).

Comment: I am the only user

Comment: Install a plugin like `wp-audit-log` (https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/) that can track actions on your site. As @cabrerahector said, content doesn't delete itself, and WordPress doesn't do it. So it's either a plugin, someone else, or a malware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot @cabrerahector

Installing these two plug-ins saved me

- All In One WP Security
- Wordfence Security